# Display the images from drawable folder as a gallery view in order to choose from

Tags: java, android, gallery, drawable

I am creating an android app which contains two activities:

1. The first activity display a default image. Clicking on the default image goto the second activity.
2. The second activity is an image gallery consist of images from the 'drawable folder in the android studio. Once the user clicks on an image, the user is brought back to the first activity with the selected image as the new profile picture.

Now I have issue when I try to get the image from the drawable folder. I have image's names in drawable folder as image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg
How do I write the part of the code that brings these 3 image to create a gallery view for user to choose from?

Comment: imageView.loadFromResource(R.drawable.image2); ?

Comment: You can loop through all the images, take a counter say i and keep incrementing it. Do some string magic append it to the end of the image. Also from your question, you seem to know about how to access the drawable images so I won't get into that